# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm simply following this tutorial on youtube. useState is giving errors.

Please help me here

```js
import React from 'react'
//import useState from 'react-dom';
import useState from 'react';

export const Tindercards = () => {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([
        {
            name: "Elon Musk",
            url:"https://...." "https://www.biography.com/.image/ar_1:1%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_1200/MTc5OTk2ODUyMTMxNzM0ODcy/gettyimages-1229892983-square.jpg"
        }
    ]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="tindercards">
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Tindercards;
```

[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i2GF.png)

Answer (score 15):

useState is not the default function from the 'react' package. Change:

```
import useState from 'react';
```

to

```
import { useState } from 'react';
```

You can leave off the curly braces only for the default function from a module/package.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurred for me when i imported **useParams from 'react'** while correct **import is from 'react-router-dom'**.
So, i supposes is directly correlated with fault imports

Answer (score 0):

- useState is not from react-dom, can be imported from react
- Also it is not default export function from react.
- import { useState } from "react";

this solved my issue.

Comment: Please do not add duplicate answers. This is already covered in the top answer.